# Difference between result.id and result['id'] in Angular/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm wonder what is difference between result.id and result['id'] in Angular/JavaScript ?
If i'm type :

```
getId(){
  this.service.getId().subscribe(
    result=>{ var i = result.id; }//this...
  )
}
```

...sometimes the compiler decorate result.id with red underline (error) then i change it to :

```
getId(){
  this.service.getId().subscribe(
    result=>{ var i = result['id']; }//with this
  )
}
```

the decoration disappear. But sometimes i can write result.id and not see any errors.

> Note that the *result* type is **any** !!!

So i'm confused a little with 2 cases. Did i miss something ?

Thanks anyway!

Comment: from a code point of view, nothing. Whatever editor you're using is doing that

Comment: Both `result.id` and `result['id']` are same

Comment: If you want not mark as error "cast" to any: `subscribe((res:any)=>{let i=result.id})`: NOTE try use "let", not "var" to define a variable, else the variable can be propagate along the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Square bracket notation allows the use of characters that can't be used with dot notation:**

```
var foo = myForm.foo[]; // incorrect syntax
var foo = myForm["foo[]"]; // correct syntax
```

**Secondly, square bracket notation is useful when dealing with property names which vary in a predictable way:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  someFunction(myForm["myControlNumber" + i]);
}
```

**Roundup:**

```
1. Dot notation is faster to write and clearer to read.
2. Square bracket notation allows access to properties containing special characters and selection of properties using variables
```

Another example of characters that can't be used with dot notation is property names that themselves contain a dot.

For example a json response could contain a property called `bar.Baz.`

```
var foo = myResponse.bar.Baz; // incorrect syntax
var foo = myResponse["bar.Baz"]; // correct syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Value is same in both the cases, the difference has been correctly pointed out by @Suneet Bansal.
May be linter in your case is causing the error.

Answer (score -1):

It depends, you are using an Object or an Array. Dot notation works while using an Object it will throw an error if using square bracket sometimes